# android: define RadioGroup onCheckChanged in XML

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, oncheckedchanged

Was wondering if I could define the `onCheckChanged` method in the layout xml file in android for a `RadioGroup`? As it stands I have done this programmatically with

`rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);`

followed by coding my `onCheckedChanged()` method, and it works perfectly as intended. Again, just wondering if I could do it in the XML similar to a `Button`, (`android:onClick=methodName`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `onClick` for each `RadioButton` in your xml. I'm not really sure of any benefits/disadvantages of this. But there doesn't appear to be anything like that for the `RadioGroup`. Its not necessarily going to know that one in the group was "changed" but that this `RadioButton` was `checked`

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

Comment: I thought that but wasnt sure about it. It does make even more sense to do that though because then rather than a case structure to evaluate which radio was selected i simply assign each their own onClick and eliminate the need for conditionals. THANKS! :D

Comment: No, problem. Glad I could clear it up for you. I guess something like that is developer preference in most cases